# Decay of Fourier coefficients of real analytic functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I would like to have any suggestion/reference to the following question. I have a differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ with discrete spectrum defined on a a suitable Sobolev space on a domain $\Omega$, generating an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions $\varphi_k$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Given a function $f\in C^{0}(\overline{\Omega})$ which is real-analytic inside $\Omega$, what can be said in general about the decay of the Fourier coefficients $f_k=(f,\varphi_k)_{L^2}$ of $f$ with respect the basis $\varphi_k$? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If the domain $\Omega$ were a closed analytic manifold and $\mathcal{L}$ were elliptic of order $m$ with analytic coefficients, the relevant result would be due to

> *Seeley, R. T.*, [**Eigenfunction expansions of analytic functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2036458), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 21, 734-738 (1969). [ZBL0183.10102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0183.10102).

**Theorem.** Denoting by $\lambda_k$ the eigenvalue of $\varphi_k$, $f$ is analytic iff $$\sup_k s^{\sqrt[m]{|\lambda_k|}} |f_k| < \infty$$ for some $s>1$.

I suppose that a similar result should apply for a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, once the boundary conditions and the self-adjointness of $\mathcal{L}$ are taken care of. But you should check that Seeley's argument continues to apply in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much! An exponential decay is indeed something which I expected. I will check Seeley's argument but as far as I see from the last page the criterion is appliable on any (self adjoint) elliptic operator $\mathcal{L}$ of any order.